# Put a variable value inside a jQuery's append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, append

I'm trying to append some divs inside another one using a for loop with jQuery, and I need to use the i value in each iteration to give an exclusive ID for each div appended. I've tried to break the string between '', concatenate the value and then reopen the string but it doesn't works.

Here's my code

```
for (i=0 ; i < stripes; i++ ){
$('.stripesWrapper').append('<div id="stripe"></div>')
}
```

And I've tried without success:

```
$('.stripesWrapper').append('<div id="stripe'.i'"></div>')
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `+` to concatenate strings....

```
 $('.stripesWrapper').append("<div id='stripe" + i + "'></div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.stripesWrapper').append('<div id="stripe'+ i +'"></div>');
```

You don't concatenate in javascript with `.` , that is php.

To concatenate in javascript/jquery just use `+`